# objective c iphone app not working as planned (table-view app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i've inserted a view before an established table view if that makes sense. ie. i had an app with a first and second view, then i put another view before the first view, now the content doesnt show up in the (now) third view!? Any ideas why that would be? Would i make to make some changes in the app delegate maybe??

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry, i wasnt sure which bit of the code would be relevant to my problem and i didnt want to flood the post with my entire code so i zipped it up if anyone can help?

Thanks

[Source Code](http://www.playlistdesigner.co.uk/ExampleApp.zip)

Comment: Your question is vague. What do you mean  that you've inserted a view before the first view? Are you talking about adding views in the UINavigationController hierarchy?

Comment: i had two apps. one was a core data app with a single view. the second was a rss parser with an inital

Comment: *ial table view then a second detail view, i tried to "stitch" the two apps together. So the app initially showed the core data view then to the rss parser table view then the detail view

Comment: but in the detail view the rss feed now doesnt show up!?

Comment: This question is too vague and broad to answer. Go through tutorials and compare their code with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is complete tutorial for a table view with navigation.](http://www.xprogress.com/post-32-uinavigationbar-tutorial-with-uitable-pushing-detail-view-using-didselectrowatindexpath-and-all-xcode-example-source-files/)

your question is extremely vague and confusing, hopefully next time you can provide some code and you might be able to get better responses from the community